Graphviz how to shrink spacing between subscript and script?
I make graphviz with math notation and sometimes the spacing between the greek letter and the subscript is a little too big. Is there a way to shrink this space?
digraph G {
X -> Y [label = <&#946;<SUB>1</SUB>>]
}



Your problem is specific to your OS and to the fonts loaded on your computer.
The output on my Linux system looks fine (no gap between the characters).
That said, try the following:
[label = "&#946;&#8321;"]
